# how to convert bool array to char variable?

Tags: c#, .net, char, boolean, type-conversion

I have a boolean array which holds some values that represent ASCII value:

```
bool[] myBoolReceived = new bool[8];
```

I try to convert it to a char so I can add it to a list that holds chars.

```
myReceivedMessage = new List<char>();
```

I tried to use `Convert.ToChar` method but it not seems to work.

Comment: A `bool` can hold two values: `true` and `false`. I am not sure what exactly you are trying to say by "convert bool array to char avariable". Can you please clarify that?

Comment: @Emz That part seems reasonably clear to me: the 8 bits of an 8-bit integer value are stored as separate elements of an array. There are a lot of things that aren't clear to me (such as why not simply use `byte`, why use 8 bits when ASCII is a 7-bit character set, which order the bits are in) that make the question hard to answer, though.

Comment: @Emz He probably means that the bool array represents bits in a byte.

Comment: I mean that if for example I have : false, true , true ,true, true, false, false,true it holds y character

Comment: @hvd, http://sticksandstones.kstrom.com/appen.html
Here it stands for 8 bit

Comment: I rest my case, then it should be fairly simple to solve, however there are a numerous amount of solutions to it that can be used.

Comment: @AlonShmeliov So what result do you expect when your bools are, say, true, false, true, false, false, true, false, false? Any combination where the first value is true is not defined in ASCII. The only valid ASCII values are 0 to 127. So then I'm left asking again, why use an array of length 8, if only 7 of those elements can be set?

Comment: @hvd Thanks got it, I repair my program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

char contains 2 bytes. you can convert bool array to a byte and then convert it to a character using `Convert` class.

```
public byte ConvertToByte(bool[] arr)
{
   byte val = 0;
   foreach (bool b in arr)
   {
      val <<= 1;
      if (b) val |= 1;
   }
   return val;
}
```

[reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/214795/Converting-Boolean-array-into-byte)